# How to access GPS data from an antenna attached through SMA

Tags: linux, windows, gps

I've been working on a system that consists of a box computer (Edge gateway 5200) that runs Windows with a Debian11 virtual machine on it. There is a program running on the VM that takes in data from a range of accelerometers and processes it, this works with no issue.

We also want GPS data to sync with this acceleration data, we were using a TEL0138 USB receiver that I was able to access using cgps however this is seeming to be very unreliable and the majority of the gps data sent through is blank. We have a backup antenna attached (https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-2108855-1.html) that is connected to a SMA attachment point on the PC.

However I am uncertain how to query this antenna for GPS information, I have used the windows GeoLocatation API and this seemed to work briefly, but is there a way to access a continuous data stream from this type of antenna in windows as I can see no way to make it visible to the VM.

Comment: Note: Antenna do not have any data. Somewhere you should have a GPS chip, which use the antenna data (and a clock) to get the GPS data, and also to elaborate such data. The chip will also decide when and how to send data. Usually not empty data (e.v. just data which tell it has no fix). It may take time indoor to have a fix

Comment: An interesting problem, but without a [mcve] it is likely to be voted-closed as a request-for-tools/software/other. Improve your question to show the smallest "hello-world" code that demonstrates particular solvable problem. Good luck!

Comment: I'm not familiar with this type of receivers but probably it appears as USB-to-serial adapter. If so, when you plug in receiver, the host should create `/dev/ttyUSB0` or something like that. You can read GPS data directly from port, or use backend, e.g. `gpsd`.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I think you are correct that there is a chip the SMA is connected to, do you know how I can query this, I am using the GeoLocation api presently and im unsure if its working. It hangs, but this may be as blank data is being sent through?